# Eureka client authentication failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, netflix-eureka

I have eureka server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Config:

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebConfig {
    
        @Value("${eureka.username}")
        private String username;
        @Value("${eureka.password}")
        private String password;
    
    
        @Bean
        public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
        
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf()
                    .disable()
                    .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin();
    
            return http.build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
            UserDetails user = User
                    .withUsername(username)
                    .password(encoder.encode(password))
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();
            return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
        }

}
```

application.properties:

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
server.port=8761

eureka.username=eureka
eureka.password=password


spring.security.user.name=eureka
spring.security.user.password=password


eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.name: ${spring.security.user.name}
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.password: ${spring.security.user.password}
```

This "works" , go into localhost:8761, input eureka/password as name/password and im in.

Now i have client that i want to register in the eureka server.

I have this in application.properties:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://eureka:password@localhost:8761/eureka
server.port=8081
spring.application.name=service-name
```

Upon starting the app i receive:

*

```
2023-10-22T17:03:40.958+02:00  WARN 2528 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure with status code 401; retrying on another server if available
2023-10-22T17:03:40.959+02:00  WARN 2528 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_ORDER-SERVICE/darlyn:order-service:8081 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

- 

I tried solution presented [here](https://zoltanaltfatter.com/2018/05/15/spring-cloud-discovery-with-spring-boot-admin/) e.g using

```
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.name: ${spring.security.user.name}
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.password: ${spring.security.user.password}
```

in server properties.

i have csrf disabled as most of the answers to this problem says its csrf problem,

i have tried to add custom restBean according to this [post](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/4137), e.g

```
@Bean
public RestTemplateTransportClientFactories restTemplateTransportClientFactories(EurekaClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier supplier)
{
    return new RestTemplateTransportClientFactories(new RestTemplateDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs(supplier));
}
```

in my client service, however the problem remains the same.

is there any solution to this problem or do i have to downgrade versions?

I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

for client as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

for server with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Using code samples from [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/current/reference/html/#service-discovery-eureka-clients) and [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka) results in the same error...

Thanks for help

Comment: Set the `server.port=8761` instead of `server.port=8081` in your client configuration.